# Disabling the security hardening options for a `nix-shell` environment

Tags: gcc, printf, nixos, nix, hardening

In an attempt to build GCC (6.3) on NixOS (16.09), within a `nix-shell`, I get this:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '<my-build-path>/coreboot/util/crossgcc/build-i386-elf-GCC/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'
test -f config.h || (rm -f stamp-h1 && make stamp-h1)
g++  -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp -I. -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/../include -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/include  -O2  -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp -I. -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/../include -I../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/include   -c -o expr.o -MT expr.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/expr.Tpo ../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/expr.c
../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/expr.c: In function 'unsigned int cpp_classify_number(cpp_reader*, const cpp_token*, const char**, source_location)':
../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/expr.c:686:18: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
        0, message);
                  ^
../../../gcc-6.3.0/libcpp/expr.c:689:39: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
           virtual_location, 0, message);
                                       ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:224: expr.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '<my-build-path>/coreboot/util/crossgcc/build-i386-elf-GCC/build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'
make: *** [Makefile:2730: all-build-libcpp] Error 2
sh ../gcc-6.3.0/mkinstalldirs <my-build-path>/coreboot/util/crossgcc/xgcc <my-build-path>/coreboot/util/crossgcc/xgcc
sh: line 3: cd: i386-elf/libgcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:10462: install-target-libgcc] Error 1
```

Where `-Werror=format-security` seems to be the reason for the failure (although I don't see this exact option in the command).
Yet in `<nixpkgs>/pkgs/development/compilers/gcc/6/default.nix` I find this:

```
hardeningDisable = [ "format" ];
```

And guess that the failure may be due to the security hardening measures of NixOS, some of which *have* to be disabled to get GCC compiled (let's assume GCC dev's know what they're doing in those functions).
Tested it with GCC 6.2 and 5.4 -- same thing.

So the question is how do I disable the hardening options (in particular `format`) for a `nix-shell` environment? Or where else those "warnings being treated as errors" come from?

Description(s) of the option(s):

- https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-hardening-in-nixpkgs
- https://blog.mayflower.de/5800-Hardening-Compiler-Flags-for-NixOS.html

---

According to this answer

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679630/nixos-setting-options-for-nix-shell

`nix-shell` has nothing to do with the Nix expressions... but when I call `make` with the `NIX_DEBUG` flag,

```
env NIX_DEBUG=' ' make crossgcc-i386
```

I get the output from `<nixpkgs>/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/add-hardening.sh`, e.g. `HARDENING: enabling format`; from what I infer that those "format security" options are actually applied when I call `make` in the `nix-shell`.

---

Perhaps I simply need to bump something via `nixos-option`, but which exactly option? I can't just `grep` it...  (there's no analogue of `dconf dump /` or `gsettings list-recursively`)

Comment: @drewbenn The warnings disappear, the compiler apparently works well, except maybe incorrectly working debug output; didn't test. The behavior should (almost) stay the same: it's just a `va_list` after all, as in `printf`, for example, but, because of some GCC's own format options (`%<`, `%>`), the argument isn't allowed to be a constant string.

Comment: Please post the solution as a self-answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: @drewbenn Fixing GCC seems to be a little bit more complicated than just inserting `"%s"` (see the Bugzilla thread). But NixOS provides a clean way to disable the Werrors for specific packages. -- The only problem here is that it apparently *isn't possible* to change the behavior of the compiler wrapper *right in the `nix-shell`*, i.e. without `-A` flag.

Comment: @Zimmi48 Done. Now it should better fit the SE paradigm, although the answer is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The `format-security` warnings *have* to be disabled, or at least not `-Werror`'d, because of this:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80895

The hardening options are imposed by the compiler wrapper, that's why they are not shown in the log.

And `hardeningDisable` is apparently the only method to affect the wrapper.

One possible solution is to create a dummy Nix expression to be used with `nix-shell -A`. For example:
copy `~/.nix-defexpr/channels_root/nixos/` into a separate place (`<nixpkgs'>`) and make it writeable,
add `<nixpkgs'>/pkgs/tools/misc/coreboot/default.nix` containing

```
{ stdenv, gcc6, flex, bison, ncurses, iasl, doxygen, zlib, isl, python }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "coreboot";

  buildInputs = [ gcc6 flex bison ncurses iasl doxygen zlib isl python ];

  hardeningDisable = [ "format" ];  # to build the cross-compiler
}
```

and register it in `<nixpkgs'>/top-level/all-packages.nix` as usual,
and, finally, call `nix-shell <nixpkgs'> -A coreboot` to create the environment needed.

Still I think it should be easier (workable for `nix-shell -p`).

Answer (score 1):

disable gcc hardening flags in a nix-shell

```
# shell.nix

{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

mkShell {
  # disable all hardening flags
  NIX_HARDENING_ENABLE = "";

  # enable default hardening flags
  #NIX_HARDENING_ENABLE = "pie pic format stackprotector fortify strictoverflow";

  buildInputs = [
    #gnumake
    #python3
    # ...
  ];
}
```

verify

```
$ NIX_DEBUG=1 gcc -v 2>&1 | grep ^HARDENING
HARDENING: disabled flags: pie pic format stackprotector fortify strictoverflow
```

based on

```
$ which gcc 
/nix/store/l0fvy72hpfdpjjs3dk4112f57x7r3dlm-gcc-wrapper-12.2.0/bin/gcc

$ grep add-hardening.sh /nix/store/l0fvy72hpfdpjjs3dk4112f57x7r3dlm-gcc-wrapper-12.2.0/bin/gcc
source /nix/store/l0fvy72hpfdpjjs3dk4112f57x7r3dlm-gcc-wrapper-12.2.0/nix-support/add-hardening.sh
```

see also: [Hardening in Nixpkgs](https://ryantm.github.io/nixpkgs/stdenv/stdenv/#sec-hardening-in-nixpkgs) in the nixpkgs manual